# I cannot understand the syntax of callback passed to the TypeORM Relations decorator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I have come across the relations in TypeORM which can be defined using various decortors.
For example -

```
@OneToOne(type => Profile, profile => profile.user)
@JoinColumn()
profile: Profile;
```

I am unable to wrap my head around the callback `type => Profile` . I have searching online as to what it means but to no avail. I also know we can pass `() =>  Profile` as well, but I would like to know what it is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If a function parameter isn't used it doesn't matter if it's there or what it's called.

Comment: I mean the 'type' keyword is for `type` aliases. What's the point of using it here?

Comment: What makes you think it's a keyword here? 'type' is a *contextual* keyword, e.g., https://www.tektutorialshub.com/typescript/identifiers-keywords-in-typescript/#reserved-words

Comment: Okay so here `type` acts as parameter to the callback, instead of the keyword?

Comment: It's easy enough to sanity-check; it's a function--follow the function's contact and debug/trace/check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing the library's source code, there's a [particular comment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/metadata-args/RelationMetadataArgs.ts#L48) that could help with your confusion:

> This type is in function because of language specifics and problems with recursive referenced classes.

In my interpretation, the relation type parameter is wrapped in a function so you can handle any relationship scenario, including self-referencing. Example:

```js
@Entity
class User {
  @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.directReports)
  @JoinColumn()
  manager: User;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.manager)
  directReports: User[];
}
```

In this case, using the same `User` class as a type decorator could cause errors. The function wrap fixes that.

I couldn't find any usage for the `type` argument on that callback, which can also be undefined as you've pointed out. It's likely a contextual keyword, as pointed in a comment, so your code is more readable.